# Python 3 windows 10 pip install error

Tags: c++, python-3.x, installation, pip

Hi i did a clean install of anconda 3 on windows 10.. but when i run from shell some install command by pip like "pip install pysam" i got that error message:

```
building 'pysam.libchtslib' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\rando\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\rando\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dqrfhm5k\\pysam\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rando\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-b5ng0_7u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rando\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dqrfhm5k\pysam\
```

I saw many posts about that and i understood that's could be a visual c++ problem.. i reinstalled it and also i installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python but the situation isn't changed..
What can I do? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Anaconda Faq](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq). The topic *How is CPython compiled?* tells you which version of VC++ you need. So install the Visual Studio version for your python version.

Then you have to find *Visual Studio Command Prompt* in the startmenu (make sure you use the 64 bit version). From there you should be able to run vcvarsall.bat and then finally to install the package.